# What is block usertools in django?

Tags: django

Following is code snippet from login.html

```
{% block usertools %}<p style = "color:white ; margin-top: 20px; font-size: 8px;">{{ site_version|default:_('v1.0.0') }}</p>{% endblock %}
```

I can't figure out what is significance of `block usertools` ? Is there any documentation for same. I can't see this block in base_site.html although.

Answer (score 2):

[Blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-block) are part of Djangos [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

You can give them any name and any predefined content.
In your case the name is `usertools`. And it displays the `site_version` inside a `paragraph`.

Any child template that inherits from that template can override the block.

```
{% comment %} child.html {% endcomment %} 
{% extends "login.html" %}

{% block usertools %}<p>My amazing blog</p>{% usertools %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's extended from admin/base.html. Normally it's empty. But in your case it should display site version on login page.